# Get depth of an abstract syntax tree in Python

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, depth

I'm trying to work with abstract syntax tree in Python 3.7, I use the library ast from Python library. I would like to know the depth of my tree created with `ast.parse`. I haven't found any built-in function in the library for this.

I have tried this with this toy example:

```
py_ast = ast.parse('''pd.read_json(elevations)''')

def depth_ast(tree, depth=0):
    branches_depth = []
    if isinstance(tree, ast.AST):
        for i, field in enumerate(tree._fields):
            child = getattr(tree, field)
            depth += 1
            branch_depth = depth_ast(child, depth)
            branches_depth.append(branch_depth)
    elif isinstance(tree, list):  # multiple cardinality
        if tree == []:
            return depth
        else:
            for i, arg in enumerate(tree):
                depth += 1
                branch_depth = depth_ast(arg, depth)
                branches_depth.append(branch_depth)
            return max(branches_depth)
    else:  # primitives
        return depth
    try:
        return max(branches_depth)
    except:
        return depth

print(depth_ast(py_ast))
```

I get a depth of 8 for this snippet of code whereas it should be 6 (`Module -> Expr -> Call -> Attribute -> Name -> 'pd'`) and I can't understand why.

Comment: The depth of a node is one more than the maximum of the depths of its children. That's not what you are computing. (Why do you increment `depth` repeatedly in a loop? Why do you even bother passing it as a parameter?)

Comment: I increment depth in a loop because several children could be present. I thought in a recursive function I have to keep a track of the depth. How do you suggest to do it ?

Comment: but all the children are equal. They don't get progressively deeper. (And my suggestion is in my first comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related concepts here:

- The *depth* of a node in a tree, which is the distance between that node and the root of the tree, and
- The *height* of a node in a tree (more accurately, the height of subtree rooted at that node), which is the maximum distance from that node to any descendant.

The depth of a tree is the maximum depth of any node; the height of a tree is the height of the root. It should be clear that these are the same value.

It's certainly possible to walk the tree recursively, passing the current depth through the recursion. This could even be useful if you needed to annotate each ast node with its depth, for some reason. But if you just want to compute the height of the tree, there's a much more natural recursive solution:

```
# This is a generic recursive algorithm
def height(node):
    return 1 + max((height(child) for child in children(node)),
                   default = 0)
```

That relies on the existence of a function which iterates over the children of a node, which is called `children` above. For the specific case of Python ASTs, we can use the `ast` module's convenience function, `iter_child_nodes`:

```py
def depth_ast(root):
    return 1 + max((depth_ast(child)
                       for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(root)),
                   default = 0)

# Or:

def depth_ast(root):
    return 1 + max(map(depth_ast, ast.iter_child_nodes(root)),
                   default = 0)
```